# click on add to list button get items added to list box from textbox and radio in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two forms,In form1 when user select radio button,enter value in text box and clicks on add to list button the (text of radio button+value of text box) should get added to a listbox in form2.

I wrote javascript function to add items and included the script in both forms i.e in form1 the function gets triggered for onclick event of add to list button and in form2 in body tag onload event.

But it is not working,can anyone help in this regard as i am new to javascript.

**Form1:**

```
<form name="orderform">
    Category: 
 <input type="radio" name="category" id="category" value="0">Apple</input>
 <input type="radio" name="category" id="category" value="1">Orange</input>
 <input type="radio" name="category" id="category" value="2">Banana</input>
 <input type="radio" name="category" id="category" value="3">Guava</input>
 <br>
 Item: <input type="text" length="30" name="item" id="item"/>
 <br>
 <input type="button" name="add" value="Add to List" onClick="addItem_list()"/>
 </form>
```

**Form2:**

```
<body onload="addItem_list()">
        <form name="items">
            Items <SELECT name="item_list" id="item_list">
                <option value="">Select item</option>
            </SELECT>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function addItem(selectbox,text,value )
{
    var item = document.createElement("OPTION");
    item.text = text;
    item.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(item);
}

function addItem_list(){
    var it=document.orderform.item.value; //getting item value from textbox
    //To determine which radio button has been selected:
    for (var i=0; i<document.orderform.category.length; i++)
    {
        if (document.orderform.category[i].checked==true)
        {
            var y = orderform.category[i].value;
        }
    }
    var val=y+" "+it;
    addItem(document.items.item_list,val,val);                
}
```

Comment: When you run at load time, the user hasn't had a chance to fill in the input field yet.

Comment: He also can't check any of the radio buttons. How do you expect this to work in the `onload` case?

Comment: You shouldn't reuse IDs, they're supposed to be unique. If you're not using the IDs for anything, just leave them out.

Comment: It works fine in the `onclick` case: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/d5U7u/

Comment: very true, never reuse ID's

Answer (score 0):

Your script does work as intended. However, your HTML is very invalid. This could break correct parsing in some browsers dependend on doctype and subsequently the correct execution of JavaScript. When use IDs then define them unique. `<input>` is a void tag, that means it must not have a closing tag! When you use an XHTML doctype, mark the open tag as self closing `<input />`. Use `<label for="the-input-id">My Label</label>` to get a clickable label connected to the input element.

Don't rely on name mapping to document and form objects. Other scripts can overwrite this names, e.g. a JS-framework could define `items` as a document property/method. Use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` / `document.querySelectorAll()` or some similar method instead.

I assume the `<body>` in the second code fragment appears in your code only once at the top of page.

Comment: Not quite. The script actually doesn't work, he's not actually grabbing any of the document elements that he wants. 'addItemList()' is crashing at the very first line of:    'var it = document.orderForm.item.value'. Look at the fiddle.

Comment: @WebWanderer It doesn't crash in my browser when markup is valid and even not with invalid markup in HTML5 doctype. But as I already stated out, relying on name mapping to document and forms isn't good a practice since it can be overwritten.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Quasimodo's clone, it isn't a good practice at all. Personally, I prefer generating all of the objects via JavaScript and then holding onto a reference of the object for later use, that way I don't need any sort of word mapping. I am curious why it's not crashing in your browser though. I'm not getting an error popup in Chrome, Firefox, or IE, but if you follow it in the debugger you can see that he is not properly grabbing the order form and that the function does not continue from there. What browser are you using?

Comment: @WebWanderer I've copied the code to a simple document with one body and it worked in Firefox 30 for me. Since DOM parsing can slow down the tasks, parsing once and store references in variables is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your not properly retrieving the 'orderForm' or the 'categories'. You need to grab those items correctly. You cannot navigate through the document just based on tag name, although that would be cool if you could. Here's the JS.

```
function addItem(selectbox,value )
{
    var item = document.createElement("OPTION");
    item.text = value;
    item.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(item);
}

function addItem_list(){
    var item =document.getElementById('item');

    var it = item.value;

    if(!it)
        it = 'blank';

    var categories = document.getElementsByTagName('category');


    //To determine which radio button has been selected:
    for (var i=0; i<categories.length; i++)
    {
        if (categories[i].checked==true)
        {
            var y = categories[i].value;
        }
    }
    var val;

    if(y)
        val = y + ' ' + it;
    else
        val = it;

    var item_list = document.getElementById('item_list');

    addItem(item_list,val);                
}
```

And now it works great! Hope that's what you were looking for!